# How can we manually resolve Azure Key Vault secrets to use with IOptions<T> in .NET 7 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, configuration, azure-keyvault, .net-7.0

I am working on a .NET 7 Web API application where I am using the `IOptions` pattern to read configuration values. However I have some configuration values that I want to retrieve from Azure Key Vault.

Here is an example of my appsettings.json:

```
 "ServiceBusConfigOption": {
    "ConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={name}.vault.azure.net/secrets/ServiceBusConnectionString/)",
    "TopicsEmailTemplate": "EmailTemplates",
    "TopicUserSetting": "UserSettings"
},

"StorageConfigOption": {
    "ConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={name}.vault.azure.net/secrets/AzureWebJobStorageConnectionString/)"

  },

"KeyVaultConfigOption": {
    "Name": "{name}",
    "Url": "https://{name}.vault.azure.net",
    "Thumbprint": "{Thumbprint}",
    "ClientId": "{ClientId}",
    "TenantId": "{TenantId}"
  }
```

And here is the `ServiceBusConfigOption` & `StorageConfigOption` classes:

```
public class ServiceBusConfigOption
    {
        public const string SectionName = nameof(ServiceBusConfigOption);
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string TopicsEmailTemplate { get; set; }
        public string TopicUserSetting { get; set; }
       
    }

 public class StorageConfigOption
    {
        public const string SectionName = nameof(StorageConfigOption);

        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

I am already using some code, but i think I am missing something here:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAppConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        configurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        // For Localhost, we're using appsettings.json file, it will not be overridden when running on Localhost
        if (!hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Localhost"))
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        }
        configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        return configurationBuilder;
    }

    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        if (!hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            var builtConfig = configurationBuilder.Build();
            var keyVaultEndpoint = $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:Name"]}.vault.azure.net/";

            var clientId = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:ClientId"];
            var thumbprint = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:Thumbprint"];
            var tenantId = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:TenantId"];

            var certificate = GetCertificate(thumbprint);

            var clientCertificateCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, certificate);

            configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultEndpoint), clientCertificateCredential);
        }
        
        return configurationBuilder;
    }
    
    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint == thumbprint);
        store.Close();

        if (cert == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to find the certificate for thumbprint:{thumbprint}");

        return cert;
    }
}
```

Program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    // Environment configuration
    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    var env = builder.Environment;

    configuration.AddAppConfiguration(env);

    // Add azure key vault configuration
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(env);

}
```

How can I modify my code to retreive the value from Azure Key Vault and have it populated in the `IOptions<ServiceBusConfigOption>` instance when injecting it into my services?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was missing one part here , I have to create `SecretClient` instance and load required secrets from azure key vault, and then added those in `configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection`. Now it is loading secrets from azure key vault and when I am accessing through `IOption<ServiceBusConfig>`, it is having actual value from azure key vault.

And I also got to know `@Microsoft.KeyVault` won't work locally.

Updated code is here for `AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration` method:

```
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(
    this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder,
    IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    if (!hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development"))
    {
        var builtConfig = configurationBuilder.Build();
        var keyVaultEndpoint = $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:Name"]}.vault.azure.net/";

        var clientId = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:ClientId"];
        var thumbprint = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:Thumbprint"];
        var tenantId = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:TenantId"];

        var certificate = GetCertificate(thumbprint);

        var clientCertificateCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, certificate);


        configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultEndpoint), clientCertificateCredential);

        var keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultEndpoint), clientCertificateCredential);

        Task.Run(() => LoadKeysFromKeyVault(configurationBuilder, keyVaultClient)).Wait();
    }

    return configurationBuilder;
}
```

Below private method is actually calling key vault and loading secrets:

```
private static async Task LoadKeysFromKeyVault(
    IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder,
    SecretClient keyVaultClient)
{
    var serviceBusConfig = configurationBuilder.Build()
        .GetSection(ServiceBusConfigOption.SectionName)
        .Get<ServiceBusConfigOption>();

    var propertiesToLoad = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { $"{ServiceBusConfigOption.SectionName}:{nameof(serviceBusConfig.ConnectionString)}", serviceBusConfig.ConnectionString },

    };

    foreach (var kvp in propertiesToLoad)
    {
        var configurationKey = kvp.Key;
        var secretName = kvp.Value;

        var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

        // Modify the configuration to replace the key value
        configurationBuilder.Sources.RemoveAt(configurationBuilder.Sources.Count - 1); // Remove the Key Vault source
        configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { configurationKey, secret.Value.Value }
        });
    }
}
```